# Как смерджить 2 numpy array разных размеров, начиная с последней строки меньшего массива?

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть 2 `np.array`
Первый:

```
[[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.]]
```

Второй:

```
[[1 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Я хочу получить 2 массива, которые будут заполнятся с конца. При чем, сначала мы берем все элементы с меньшего массива, а потом дополняем финальным массив недостающими элементами с большего массива.
Вот примеры массивов:

```
[[0., 0., 0.],
[1., 1., 2.],
[3., 4., 5.],
[6., 7., 8.]]
```

Второй массив:

```
[[0., 0., 0.],
[6., 7., 8.],
[3., 4., 5.],
[1., 1., 2.]]
```

Как мне смержить 2 массива таким образом, чтобы результат наполнялся с конца?

При чем, в первом случае, как видите, последней строкой финального массива есть последняя строка меньшего массива, а во втором - первая строка меньшего массива

Спасибо

Comment: первый массив - всегде 2д-тензор из нулей?

Comment: Да тут срезом небось можно. Просто скопировать бОльший массив, а потом на нужное место срезом в него записать меньший массив. Всё.

Comment: да, первый всегда тензор из нулей

Comment: Ну если из нулей, тогда вообще `np.zeros` использовать вместо первого массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При исходных:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0.]])

arr2 = np.array([[1, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]])
```

более-менее универсальное решение:

```
res = np.pad(arr2, ((arr1.shape[0]-arr2.shape[0], 0), (0, arr1.shape[1]-arr2.shape[1])))
```

res:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

ну и

```
res1 = np.pad(np.flipud(arr2), ((arr1.shape[0]-arr2.shape[0], 0), (0, arr1.shape[1]-arr2.shape[1])))
```

res1:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [6 7 8]
 [3 4 5]
 [1 1 2]]
```

Если же вы знаете, что в итоговом массиве должна быть всего лишь первая строка из нулей, то делается ещё проще:

```
res2 = np.concatenate(([[0,0,0]], arr2))
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

```
res2 = np.concatenate(([[0,0,0]], np.flipud(arr2)))
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```